# How to convert $0$ to $1$ and any whole number greater than Zero to $0$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am stuck on converting $0$ to $1$ and any whole number greater than Zero to $0$. Is there a mathematical way for doing so?Also how to notate it when using it in a function?

Comment: You can simply declare a function $f$ that does that, that is allowed into math, it doesn't need a formula. Why do you need that?

Comment: @Santropedro $0*0$ remains $0$

Comment: Yes, I edited, sorry for that. Can you say what kind of formula, wich with symbols, are you looking for? sum, product, cosine, square root?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple$$f(x)=\begin {cases} 1&x=0\\0 &x \gt 0 \end {cases}$$ does just what you asked.  As people unreasonably do not like definitions by cases, you could also say $1-H(x)$ where $H(x)$ is the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).  Unfortunately definitions of the step function at zero differ, so you have to make clear that you mean $H(0)=0$.

Comment: I think I can use the Heaviside step function as $H(x-(x-1))$ where $x$ is my input.Thanks

Comment: Then you need to make sure people understand that $H(0)=1$.  This also fails for fractional values between $0$ and $1$ but maybe your $x$ is always a whole number.

Comment: Yes it will always be a whole number , and $H(0)$ will never happen.It will always be $H(-1)$ or $H(1)$

Answer (score 1):

If one doesn't mind limits, we can say
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1-x^2+x^4}{1+x^4}\right)^n
=\left\{\begin{array}{}
1&\text{if }x=0\\
0&\text{if }x\ne0\
\end{array}\right.
$$

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is a nonnegative integer, what about:

$${1 \choose n+1}$$

If not what about,

$${1 \choose \lceil n+1 \rceil}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
f(x) = \frac{1+(-1)^{2^{|x|}-1}}{2} = \begin {cases} 1&x=0\\0 &x \ne 0 \end {cases}
$$